# FedEx service - "Free method" impossibly affecting rates

Tags: shipping, configuration, fedex

The FedEx shipping method allows one to set a free shipping method and set a minimum order amount for it to be applied.

**Item in Cart**

- Product Weight = 22.17lbs
- Qty = 7

**Configuration A**

- Packages Request Type = "Use Origin Weight"
- Free Method = "Ground"
- Free Shipping w/Minimum Order = "Disable"
- Minimum Order Amount = null
- Allowed Methods = Ground
- Max Package Weight = 150

**Configuration B**

- Packages Request Type = "Use Origin Weight"
- Free Method = "Disabled"
- Free Shipping w/Minimum Order = "Disable"
- Minimum Order Amount = null
- Allowed Methods = Ground
- Max Package Weight = 150

**Configuration C**

- Packages Request Type = "Divide To Equal Weight"
- Free Method = "Disabled"
- Free Shipping w/Minimum Order = "Disable"
- Minimum Order Amount = null
- Allowed Methods = Ground
- Max Package Weight = 150

**Rates**

- Configuration A = 146.52
- Configuration B = 69.68
- Configuration C = 73.26

The rates returned by Configuration A are double that of Configuration C and it seems to be related to how Magento breaks the shipment up into number of boxes. Since the item weighs 22.17lb and there are 7 in the cart, the shipment exceeds 150lb maximum. If there are only 6 in the cart, both configurations return the same rates (as expected).

Additionally, as the quantity increases and the 150lb max is exceeded for each box that is needed, the price doubles again.

**Aside from this, why the discrepancy in rates between Configuration A and B? Why would setting the free shipping method to Ground cause the price to double?**

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Or a reason?

Comment: When you 'Divide To Equal Weight' for all request what is returned for Config A & B? What are you allowed methods? Make sure Packaging is 'Your Packaging'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that in the case where your product weight exceeds the 150 pound maximum, you're hitting the penalty by FedEx for very heavy packages.  They do this because they don't want to hurt their employees who have to lift extremely heavy packages.

If you are using a free method, then FedEx will not charge the end customer to ship the package, and the shipping rate in the cart will be free.  You as a company will incur shipping, but it's free for the end user.

So the good news is that even if you have this as the free method, your shipping department should know that it's going to be cheaper to break up the shipment into two different boxes.  To the end user, it doesn't matter, because it's free.

I'm not sure why the rates for B are less than A.  It's possible that there is another free shipping method turned on that is overriding the Fedex settings.  It could also be other items in the cart, or a catalog price rule, perhaps.

I hope this helps...